# What is the error undefined reference to `vtable for classname'

Tags: c++, oop, cmake

I am having a hard time understanding why I get the error `` undefined reference to `vtable for Item' ``

```
├── build_debug
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeFiles
│       └── Makefile
├── build_release
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Item.cc
    ├── Item.h
    ├── main.cc
    └── Makefile
```

contents of `item.h`

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

class Item
{
public:
    Item();
    virtual ~Item();
};
#endif
```

contents of `item.cc`

```
#include "item.h"
Item::Item(){}
```

And the contents of `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_compile_options(-fpermissive)

set(SOURCES 
    main.cc
    item.h
    item.cc)

message (${SOURCES})
add_executable(app ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: Where do you define the virtual destructor?

Comment: @273K I thought the error was related to the constructor

Comment: Constructor cannot be virtual and is irrelevant to vtable.